# EntityManager is null if not created Manually

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, hql

I work on a maven project which is deployed as a runnable jar on a server.

Unfortunately my EntityManager stays null if I not assign it manually.

Persistence.xml

```java
<persistence-unit name="GreedTechDB">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://CORRECT_URL/GreedTechV1"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="CORRECT_USER"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="CORRECT_PASSWORD"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"    value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql"   value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Then in my BaseSource,java

```java
public class BaseSource implements Serializable {

    @Getter
    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    private JPAQueryFactory queryFactory = null;

    protected JPAQueryFactory jpaQueryFactory() {
        if (queryFactory == null)
            queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(em);
        //em.clear();
        return queryFactory;
    }
}
```

When my MainSource does the most Part of Insert//Updates

```java
public class MainSource extends BaseSource {

    public List<Streamer> getChannelsToJoin() {
        QStreamer qStreamer = QStreamer.streamer;
        return jpaQueryFactory().selectFrom(qStreamer).where(qStreamer.modules.like("%bot%")).fetch();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void insertPengStats(int channel_id, int user_id, boolean success, int time_done) {
        PengStats stats = new PengStats();
        stats.setChannelId(channel_id);
        stats.setUserId(user_id);
        stats.setKilled(success);
        stats.setTimeDone(time_done);
        stats.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
        em.persist(stats);
    }


}
```

I tried to assign the EntityManager manually, then the Selects all worked but my Update/Inserts were not processed correctly.
No Exception was thrown but no data was persisted either...

Comment: You mention it is deployed on a server, but not what server or how you've configured it. Judging by you putting in jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url in the persistence.xml, you haven't configured this to be container managed persistence - check your logs and I'm sure your server will be warning you about it not knowing what to do with your @PersistenceContext or that it is loading it with a default one instead of your named "GreedTechDB"

Comment: Yes i deploy the jar on a server and it is started with "java -jar " command in the CLI. Unfortunately i do not get any logs. Neither in Deployment nor in Debug mode on localhost

Comment: How do you create instance of MainSource? I hope not something like new MainSource()?

Comment: What configuration did you do so that the container will inject the "GreedTechDB" into your EntityManager instances? I'd suggest you look at tutorials out there for your server (still not mentioned) on using JPA within it - for transactional management, you are going to need the container to manage the datasource